# correct way to add an event to the iOS calendar with standard dialog?

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar, eventkit

currently im using this code snippet to add an event to the calendar

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date as Date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date as Date)
self.addEventToCalendar(title: "lol", description: "lal", startDate: date, endDate: date)
```

which is not refined, but it works. I have 2 questions:

is there a way to use the same form for adding an event to the iOS calendar as you see when iOS recognises a date in your e-mails?

is there a way to directly transform a string in to a date? I get the date from the backend like: 31.12.2016 22:30:00 (DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS).

Comment: If you use a textView, it can automatically detect dates.

Comment: See the documentation for the `EventKitUI` framework and look into `DateFormatter`.

Comment: ok nice to hear that there is some function. What about the Dialog provided by the system? There is no way to call it? I like it because you can edit your title, i guess i have to do it myself?